# Can you delete / remove / update a decentralized asset in the NXT Asset Exchange?

Tags: nxt, decentralized-assets

I made a mistake when creating a nxt asset on the asset exchange. How do I delete it or just update the description?

If I can't do neither, how do I get it delisted if its even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting, updating and delisting are not supported now.